# FBX Import - What do these settings mean?

Tags: export, import, .fbx

When importing an FBX file, most of the settings are self-explainable, however, there are some settings that I'm curious to know the meaning/use of. These are:

**(1)** Import User Properties (what are user properties in an FBX file, doesn't FBX only store meshes, textures, and animations?).

**(2)** Import Enums As Strings (what are Enums and Strings?).

**(3)** Use Pre/Post Rotation (what are pre/post rotation?). Hovering the mouse over these in Blender doesn't explain them very well, and the Blender manual just says "TODO." on these (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_fbx.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FBX can hold more information than you think, things like information about the modifiers you use, however there are limits.

I cant find a list about the user properties in Blender which are supported in FBX but I know there is one for 3ds Max:

https://download.autodesk.com/us/fbx/2013/3ds_Max_FBX_Plug-in_Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-21B34883-49AC-46BF-80A6-38D26AFC6C19.htm,topicNumber=d30e807

Say you wanted to export a file from 3ds Max to an FBX, this is all the information it can store apart from the usual meshes textures and animations.